# Access restricted site from internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dll

I have a chating software - voice and cam, and someone uses the same software but he has a new addition. My software need to install ajax file, cab file to login the site. He uses `dll file` put it on the `cab file` to block my site, when any user go to him and install his cab Automatically writes in the Registry this keys :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\saudidos.com

to block my site from internet explorer and he is add addition on Task Scheduler to Re-register him file File every 10 minutes

can anyone help me to fix this problem on the html

Thank you.

Comment: Unable to understand what exactly is your problem. Do you want to block a site? Or want to block the software?

Comment: i want skip the block site with out make program i need way on asp or html to skip thie block HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet